# Python TensorFlow v2, locating contrib.training

Tags: python, tensorflow, import

I am using some [code](https://github.com/Elvenson/midiMe) based on Tensorflow 1.x and I am using the latest version of TensorFlow (2.8).

I have run `tf_upgrade_v2` (following [these migration instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/upgrade)) on the python file to generate a new compatible file.

However, this doesn't work with the line of code; `from TensorFlow.contrib import training as contrib_training`.

Getting the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'`

I understand that `contrib` has been deprecated, so the modules have been moved around. But I haven't been able to find where this training module has moved to or if it has been deleted. I have looked for information first on this [document on the status of tf.contrib](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md) and after this [spreadsheet on TF2.0 Symbols map](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FLFJLzg7WNP6JHODX5q8BDgptKafq_slHpnHVbJIteQ) and haven't found any information on the fate of this training module;
[image]

I have also tried looking around TensforFlow/tf.compat.v1 but with no success.

Of course uninstalling this version of TensorFlow and instead installing an earlier version is an option. But not an option that I am overly keen on.

I feel like I may be missing something fairly obvious here...

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this error - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'` is,  `tf.contrib` has been deprected to use in `Tensorflow 2.x`. You can use **Tensorflow Addons** or **Tensorflow Slim** in the pace of `tf.contrib` api.

Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/migrate_tf2#remove_usage_of_tfcontrib) link for more details.